# Help with a question on vectors, their representation as partial derivatives, and their geometrical relationships.

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

I have the relation (in tensor or indicial notation):
$$\tag{1} f_{n_i} = -k \frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}$$
where $f_{n_i}$ is the [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of the vector $f_i$ in the direction of unit vector $n_i$, $k$ is a scalar, $v$ is a scalar, and $\partial/\partial n_i$ denotes differentiation along the spatial direction of $n_i$.

**Question1**: Since $f_{n_i}$ is a vector would that make the term $\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}$ a vector? If "yes", could you explain the relationship between the vector notations such as those given in Eqn(1) on the left-hand and right-hand sides?

**Question2**: If we want to rearrange Eqn(1) to solve for $k$, one might naively write
$$\tag{2} k=f_{n_i}/(\partial v/\partial n_i)$$
But if $\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}$ is a vector then this would not work since we cannot divide a vector by a vector. Since $k$ is a scalar I suppose we have to perform a scalar (dot) product of the two vectors. How would one write this operation?

**Question3**: Using matrix notation, I know the geometrical relationship between the vectors $\bf{f}$, $\nabla v$, and $k$ is
$$\tag{3} k=\frac{|\bf{f}| cos \theta}{|\nabla v|}$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors $\bf{f}$ and $\nabla v$. Based on the answer to Question2 -- which would be written in indicial notation -- how would one derive (i.e., arrive at) Eqn(3) while continuing to use indicial notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plane, with Euclidean geometry, we can think of vectors as "arrows", say, with direction and length, in that plane.  With more complicated geometry, say a sphere, or the more general differential geometry, we cannot do that.  On the sphere, for example, at every point, there is a "tangent plane" and the vectors at any point are "tangent vectors" and lie in that tangent plane.  If we are given a function, f, defined at every point on that sphere it's derivative, with respect to the coordinate variables or, more generally, the "gradient", $\nabla f$, gives a vector at every point, a "vector field",  You are really working with vector **fields**, not individual vectors.  Your "v" and "$f_{n_i}$"  are vector fields, not vectors.

Yes, given $f_{n_i}= -k\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}$, you cannot solve for k by dividing by $\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}$ since that is a vector.  But you can calculate the lengths of the two vectors: $|f_{n_i}|= k|\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}|$  and then calculate that $k= \frac{|f_{n_i}|}{|\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}|}$.

Comment: For clarification, would my $v$ be a scalar field and my $f_{n_i}$ be a vector field? (and my $\frac{\partial v}{\partial n_i}$ is a vector field?)